# SymPy with Octave?

Tags: python, anaconda, octave, sympy

I cannot get SymPy to work with my Octave. I have installed sympy through Anaconda and I have Python installed. I also have added the Python environment variables to my Path.

How can I get Octave to recognize SymPy being installed?

For reference, I am using Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: `sympy` is a Python module.  Are you looking for `OctSymPy`?  https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: I receive the following message from Octave:
Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
error: Python cannot import SymPy: have you installed SymPy?
    Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.
error: called from
    assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 123 column 7
    python_ipc_popen2 at line 79 column 5
    python_ipc_driver at line 59 column 15
    python_cmd at line 163 column 11
    valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
    assumptions at line 82 column 7

Comment: You may need an added `symbolic` module: https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy

Comment: I'm honestly so frustrated at this point. I've done it correctly on 3 computers a long time ago, but I cannot seem to get it to work here. How would I install it from that site? Thanks.

Comment: If you've done this in the past, then you probably are miles ahead of anyone else online now.  Your initial question sounded like you were a novice at Octave/sympy.  Sounds like this is more of a question for the `symbolic` developers, not general `sympy/python` users.  Context matters when asking questions like this.

Comment: I don't know what to do with the github sites I am always referred to. I honestly don't know what to do at this point. I just want it to work like it does on my other machines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59700101/cannot-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sympy)

Comment: No because I am the one who posted that.

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate questions. You should [edit] one of your posts to include more information so it’s answerable, and delete the other one.

Answer (score 2):

I know the issue is old but it's worth answering. I had the same exact problem up until now. I am in Linux so I will report the answer for Linux although I believe with appropriate dedication this solution will be helpful also for Windows.
The issue relied for me on the fact that I had multiple versions of Python installed. The default was 3.9.7, Octave was set to use 3.8. This is because 3.8 is installed in the default path /usr/bin/python3.8 whilst the 3.9.7 is installed under the Anaconda path /home/username/anaconda3/bin/python3.9.
When you install SymPy in my case it was installed for the 3.9.7 Python and therefore unrecognizable by Octave. So what you can do is set Octave to use the default Python environment(in my case Python 3.9.7 under Anaconda).
However you will need to pass the full path of the distribution to Octave. So the commands in Octave are:

```
setenv PYTHON /home/username/anaconda3/bin/python3.9
sympref reset
```

And you should be good to go.