# Cannot resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'

Tags: python, anaconda, octave, sympy

Can someone help me resolve the following issue? I'm getting extremely frustrated. I've installed Octave with the symbolic package before, but I forgot how I did it, and I'm getting very upset at myself currently. I've installed Anaconda, Python, and Octave and I keep getting the following error message:

```
Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
error: Python cannot import SymPy: have you installed SymPy?
    Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.
error: called from
    assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 123 column 7
    python_ipc_popen2 at line 79 column 5
    python_ipc_driver at line 59 column 15
    python_cmd at line 163 column 11
    valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
    assumptions at line 82 column 7
    syms at line 97 column 13
```

Comment: The error message says `Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.` Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried this. I will paste what I get

Comment: SymPy is a Python library used by Symbolic for almost all features.

Attempting to run python -c "import sympy; print(sympy.__version__)"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
status =  1
output =

Unfortunately status was non-zero: probably Python cannot import sympy.

  * Is there an error message above?

  * Do you have SymPy installed?  If not, please try to install it and
    try again.

Comment: 悅ଖꊨ̲  * If you do have SymPy installed, maybe it's installed for a different
    Python interpreter than the one we found?  Please try "setenv" as
    described above to change your python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to install it via `pip install sympy`?

Comment: I'm not sure what this means or how to do this. Can you tell me how to install it this way? I went to Anaconda and typed conda install sympy then conda update sympy.

Comment: Just as conda, pip is used to install packages. Usually you get these ModuleNotFoundErrors if the required package is not (correctly) installed. Can you check if your conda install sympy completed successfully?
You can do this with `conda list` which lists all installed packages

Comment: I receive the following:
```
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sympy) (1.1.0)
```

Comment: Hmm, then it should theoretically be installed. My only remaining guess is that you might have several python versions installed and that the installed sympy package is in another version than the one you use to run your program.
But I wouldn't expect that to be very likely.

Comment: Actually, I did install Python twice. Should I Uninstall Python entirely, and how do I choose which one to Uninstall?

Comment: That's a bit difficult to tell without knowing what your system currently looks like. Usually you don't even need to install Python itself since it already comes with Anaconda.

Comment: Ok. I uninstalled all versions of Python and Octave and re-installed one Python and one Octave. I still get the same error message above. I still have the same message inside of Anaconda. I'm so confused about what's going on!